# How do I create more than one instances of the Quartz.Net scheduler?

Tags: quartz.net

Is it safe to run multiple instances of the quartz.net scheduler?
If so, how do I do it?

Comment: can you explain the scenario which needs multiple scenarios? If you want to feed jobs through one scheduler and run jobs in another you can create scheduler for feeding jobs with property <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.ZeroSizeThreadPool, Quartz" />;

Comment: I need to run some jobs sequentially AND on one thread. A scheduler with 1 thread and another with a regular thread pool would solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use quartz_jobs.xml to configure jobs and create StatefulJobs and use job chaining for running jobs sequentially in one thread scheduler(pointing to RAMJobStore); another scheduler pointing to data store can run simultaneously
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/faq#FAQ-chain

If you need to persist all jobs to single database, you can use 2 schedulers with clustering but you won't get to choose which job runs on which scheduler, so your jobs will run sequentially but may not run on single thread scheduler. 2schedulers can be run, if having 2 quartz table sets with different prefix is not an issue.
http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/cookbook/MultipleSchedulers

Comment: you can have single thread scheduler pointing to quartz tables with some prefix, using configuration <add key="quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix" value="QRTZ_" />

Comment: I should need only one configure files for the two schedulers.  they differ by the number of threads in the pool.  I do not wish to create two separate config files as future sync between the two would be a nightmare.  And I am not using a database store.  How do I achieve this?

Comment: properties can be set in code;                                                                                                                    NameValueCollection scheduler1Properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "SingleThreadScheduler";
properties["quartz.threadPool.type"] = "Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz";
properties["quartz.threadPool.threadCount"] = "1";

Comment: I still need to use the config file to specify all properties except one.  Is there a function that takes a NameValueCollection that overrides the settings in the file?

Comment: you can pass the collection to scheduler creation constructor. Why don't you access that one property you want to keep in config file and set it in collection ?